# How to cross reference IDs from API responses

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have two API responses. One is an **array of objects (Products)** and another is **a single object (User).** Each Product has an ID property that corresponds to a userID inside of User. For each product I want to display a User's info (name, email) by matching userID to the ID that is in Product.

I am attempting to do this by passing a property called userID from the parent, **OrderList**, to the child, **UserInfo.**

```
export class OrderList extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchOrdersAndUsers();
  }

  renderList() {
    return this.props.orders.map(order => {
      return (
        <div key={order.orderId}>
          <h3>{order.name}</h3>
          <UserInfo userId={order.id} />
        </div>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.renderList()}</div>;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    orders: state.theOrders.ordersArr
  };
};
```

I have an action that should fetch me a single user by passing it an ID. And another Action that should fetch all Orders and 1 user. (There is no endpoint to fetch all users at once)

```
export const fetchUser = id => {
  return async dispatch => {
    const results = await user.get(`/users/${id}`);

    dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_USER', payload: results.data.user });
  };
};

export const fetchOrdersAndUsers = (dispatch, getState) => {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    await dispatch(fetchOrders());

    const allOrders = getState().theOrders.ordersArr;
    allOrders.forEach(order => {
      return dispatch(fetchUser(order.id));
    });
  };
};
```

Inside my UserInfo component I passed the userID property from the parent to the fetchUser function but i get errors

```
class UserInfo extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>{this.props.userId}</h4> 
        <p>{this.props.fetchUser(this.props.userId).name}</p> // doesn't work
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

How can I extract the ID from product match it with the correct userId?

Answer (score 0):

When you dispatch `fetchUser` action in `UserInfo` component, it updates the state (assuming your reducer is set up to do so). It does not return the user object to your component. So you need to pass the user object from the store to your component as a prop, the same way you are doing it for `orders` in `OrderList` with `mapStateToProps`.

I recommend you restructure your components and change how you are calling your API to make this process more efficient.

For example, try fetching both users and orders in `OrderList`'s `componentDidMount` and pass the `user` object down to `UserInfo`. Here's a possible way of doing it (note that you need to update your actions and reducers to get all the users and put them in the store):

OrderList:

```
export class OrderList extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchOrdersAndUsers();
    this.props.fetchUsers();
  }

  renderList() {
    return this.props.orders.map(order => {
      return (
        <div key={order.orderId}>
          <h3>{order.name}</h3>
          <UserInfo userId={order.id} user={this.props.users[order.id]} />
        </div>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.renderList()}</div>;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    orders: state.theOrders.ordersArr,
    users: state.users
  };
};
```

UserInfo:

```
class UserInfo extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>{this.props.userId}</h4> 
        <p>{this.props.user.name}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, there is no way to fetch a list of users at once. I can only fetch one user at a time. I updated the post to show my 'fetchOrdersAndUsers' action

Comment: You can still do it by calling `fetchUser` action in `UserInfo`'s `componentDidMount` and pass it as a prop with `mapStateToProps` on `UserInfo`.